# Increase space between lines (not globally) by using fancyvrb

Tags: spacing, fancyvrb

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}%
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small,commandchars=\\\{\}}
\newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\SpecialCharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DocumentationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{Highlighting}[]
\DecValTok{5} \SpecialCharTok{+} \DecValTok{32}
## [1] 8
\DocumentationTok{\#\# this is the start of an R script}
\DocumentationTok{\#\# the heading provides some information about the file}
\DecValTok{5} \SpecialCharTok{+} \DecValTok{32}
## [1] 8
\end{Highlighting}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Please advise how to achieve this...

PS: Don't want to give an enter mark, like some tag `\vspace{4pt}`, etc...

Comment: what about \\\[4pt] ?

Comment: @WinnieNotThePooh Hopefully, it's not working...

Comment: Well, you *need* to mark that space somehow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

One way would be to split  the environment and add some space in the middle.

If it's just a rare occurrence ...

**Or** add some space between the lines of the listing

[image: e]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}%
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{%  
%       frame=single,framesep=0mm,framerule=0.1pt,
%       rulecolor=\color{green},
    fontsize=\small,commandchars=\\\{\}}
\newcommand{\DecValTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.81}{#1}}
\newcommand{\SpecialCharTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.00}{#1}}
\newcommand{\DocumentationTok}[1]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.56,0.35,0.01}{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\SpaceTok}[1]{\vspace*{-10pt}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{Highlighting}[]
    \DecValTok{5} \SpecialCharTok{+} \DecValTok{32}
    ## [1] 8
    \DocumentationTok{\#\# this is the start of an R script}
    \DocumentationTok{\#\# the heading provides some information about the file}
    \DecValTok{5} \SpecialCharTok{+} \DecValTok{32}
    ## [1] 8
\end{Highlighting}

\centering aprox. 4pt added   to baselineskip = \the\baselineskip

\begin{Highlighting}[]
    \DecValTok{5} \SpecialCharTok{+} \DecValTok{32}
    ## [1] 8
\end{Highlighting}
\vspace*{\dimexpr -2\baselineskip+8pt} % add ~ 4pt <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\begin{Highlighting}
    \DocumentationTok{\#\# this is the start of an R script}
    \DocumentationTok{\#\# the heading provides some information about the file}
    \DecValTok{5} \SpecialCharTok{+} \DecValTok{32}
    ## [1] 8
\end{Highlighting}

\begin{Highlighting}[]
    \DecValTok{5} \SpecialCharTok{+} \DecValTok{32}
    ## [1] 8 \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][8pt]{}  % add ~ 4pt <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \DocumentationTok{\#\# this is the start of an R script}
    \DocumentationTok{\#\# the heading provides some information about the file}
    \DecValTok{5} \SpecialCharTok{+} \DecValTok{32}
    ## [1] 8
\end{Highlighting}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working, is this possible to meet the output within single `Highlighting` environment? please suggest...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Please the the updated answer. I added another way.

Comment: Thanks will check and get back to you

Comment: Yes, it's working fine, thanks a lot...